# How to configure Hazelcast for use with Google App Engine Flex instances?

Tags: google-app-engine, hazelcast

I would like to use Hazelcast with Google App Engine Flex instances.  I found this plugin https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast-gcp however it only supports compute engine. More specifically this plugin uses this api endpoint https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/rest/v1/ which I discovered does not return App Engine Flex instances.

I found this article https://hazelcast.com/blog/hazelcast-on-gcp-google-cloud-platform-part-1/ however it too is based on compute engine and does not apply to App Engine.

Lastly I examined the VPC firewall rules for my GCP project and found that there is a "default-allow-internal" rule that implies internal traffic between instances is allowed however the instances are not able discover each other.

Any advice on how to get Hazelcast working on Google App Engine Flex would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast-gcp/issues/new Can you create a Feature Request issue on the github repository?

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to Hazelcast you can use [Memorystore](https://cloud.google.com/memorystore/docs/redis/) which is a google managed Redis Service.

If you want to use this alternative for the configuration you can follow [this](https://cloud.google.com/memorystore/docs/redis/connect-redis-instance-flex) which will guide you step by step on how to achieve it.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, there is no discovery plugin supporting Google App Engine for Hazelcast. As you already found out, https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast-gcp is dedicated to Google Compute Engine only.